# Counting trains by type code

Tags: c++

> A train operator has decided to hire an observer to track the
>   different types of trains transiting at a major train platform in
>   Europe. Write a program, using a for loop, to track the different
>   train types at the major train station.
>
> The different types of trains are shown in the following table:
>
> ```
> Train types | Train code
>
> Inter-city  | 23            
> Regional    | 51        
> Overnight   | 72
> ```
>
> The program should ask the user to enter five sets of train codes.
>
> The program should then count the number of train codes entered and
>   display the statistics.
>
> #### Sample run
>
> ```
> Enter train type #1: 23
> Enter train type #2: 23
> Enter train type #3: 51
> Enter train type #4: 72
> Enter train type #5: 23
> ```
>
> #### Sample output
>
> ```
> Statistics:
> 3 Inter-city trains
> 1 Regional train
> 1 Overnight train
> ```

Can you please check whether this code is correct, and maybe make it shorter?

```c++
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int train;
    int InterCity = 0;
    int Regional = 0;
    int Overnight = 0;

    cout << "          ------Trains------" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= 5; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter train type #" << i << ": ";
        cin >> train;

        if (train == 23)
        {
            InterCity++;
        }
        else if (train == 51)
        {
            Regional++;
        }
        else if (train == 72)
        {
            Overnight++;
        }
    }
    cout << "\n        ------Statistics------" << endl;
    cout << InterCity  << " InterCity trains." << endl;
    cout << Regional << " Regional trains." << endl;
    cout << Overnight << " Overnight trains." << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Just some details which jumped to my eye: You are not asking your user to input 5 trains. What happens (or what should happen) if the user enters a number which there is no train for? Also, you are always outputting "trainS", even if there is only 1. It will say `1 Overnight trains` although it should say `1 Overnight train`. As Nishant suggested you could use a switch...

Comment: how do you add a switch may i ask, im not too good at c++ yet

Comment: Have a look at http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/switch

Comment: User feedback and cosmetic messages such as "Enter train #", "--trains--" or "--statistics--" should generally be written to cerr, not cout. This will make your program easier to run from automated scripts, as the script writer does not have to separate them from the data output.

Answer (score 4):

Use a `switch` statement.  Add a default condition to show the error message when the entered train type is not matched with any specified train type.

```
switch (train) {
    case 23: InterCity++; break;
    case 51: Regional++;  break;
    case 72: Overnight++; break;
    default: // TODO: error handling
}
```

Comment: how do you add a switch may i ask, im not too good at c++ yet...

Comment: Google it... You will find some good tutorials for it.

Answer (score 3):

Your situation qualifies for the [Rule of Three](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_%28computer_programming%29).

Given the assignment, it is slightly overkill, but it's good practice for more complex situations.

My code is actually slightly longer! But your main goal should be maintainability, readability (I assume "for someone qualified enough").

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using namespace std;

class TrainType // A type of train, including the amount
{
public:
    TrainType(string name = "") :
        name_(name), amount_(0)
    {    }

    string getName() const { return name_; }
    int getAmount() const { return amount_; }
    void incrementAmount() { amount_++; }

private:
    string name_;
    int amount_;
};

int main()
{
    const int number_of_trains = 5;

    map<int, TrainType> train_types; // map id -> matching type of train
    train_types[23] = TrainType("InterCity");
    train_types[51] = TrainType("Regional");
    train_types[72] = TrainType("Overnight");

    cout << "          ------Trains------" << endl;
    for (int i = 1; i <= number_of_trains; i++)
    {
        cout << "Enter train type #" << i << ": ";
        int train_id;
        cin >> train_id;

        if (train_types.find(train_id) == train_types.end()) // Is the train_id invalid ?
        {
            cout << "Error: train type " << train_id << " is invalid";
            continue;
        }
        // If not, we increment its amount
        train_types[train_id].incrementAmount();
    }

    cout << "\n        ------Statistics------" << endl;
    for(map<int, TrainType>::const_iterator it = train_types.begin(); it != train_types.end(); it++)
    {   // For each TrainType in train_types, display the result :
        cout << it->second.getAmount()  << " " << it->second.getName() << " train(s)." << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Some explanations :

- I have named `const int number_of_trains = 5;` It is good practice to named those values, as it makes comprehension and possible future changes much easier.
- There is only 1 place in the new code where we write the information "there is a type of train named Intercity" (the `train_types[23] = TrainType("InterCity");`), compared to 3 places in your code.
- The rest of the code only needs to know that there are several train types that can be found with an id.
- My code creates a class `TrainType` used to store a name and an amount.
  Then, I need to store those different train types in a container (`train_types`). There are several simple containers in the `std` that can do that: `vector`, `list`, `map`.
  I have chosen the map as I need to access the train by an id, instead of an index (where `vector` is the best), and as I don't need to make lots of non-tailed insertion/deletion (where list is the best).

I suggest you check [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) for a complete description of the map container.

Comment: This is not _slightly_ overkill, it simply _is_ overkill. OP doesn't know how to make a switch and you are throwing class, access modifiers and maps at him. Your OO design is nice I guess. However, I'd suggest OP learns one thing after the other. Good practice assumes you know how to get things done in the first place. Still this might be useful for slightly more advanced programmers...

Comment: I started to write this before the OP wrote he/she doesn't how to make a switch. Indeed, it is indeed currently too advanced for him/her, however he/she can come back to this assignment later on. Also, it can be useful for others.

Comment: Ugh, no. using .find() and hashing function should kill performance of this code considerably. They are cheap, but not no cost and if we scale the problem significantly they *will* hurt in the long run

Comment: The current issue is small, and thus `map`performance issues are hardly relevant. It looks like a homework, scaling is extremely unlikely. Moreover, if someone did try to scale the program, I'd suggest benchmarking 1st - after all, entering the numbers 1 by 1 with `cin` is the biggest issue. The next input system may still be the bottleneck. Thus my choice of simplicity over performance.